# Why is my append function broken?

Tags: prolog

I was doing some programming in Prolog and suddenly my append function stopped working.

It only stopped working for the file I was working on, so I decided to try and figure it out.

I tested a lot of things and in the end figured out that a full stop in the wrong place had caused the error.

Why does a fullstop in my code cause the entire append function to stop working?

Here is my code:

```
cheat([Head|Tail], OldList, RunList):-
   cheat(Tail, TempList, SubList),
   append([Head], TempList, OldList),
   createTinyList(OldList, TinyListUnlist),
   copyList(CopyList, OldList),        
   subtract(CopyList, TinyList, OldList),
   lister(TinyListUnList, TinyList).  % <----THE FULL STOP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
append(TinyList, SubList, RunList).
```

Comment: Don't you get some warnings?

Comment: Well there is a **dot** over there, so that means "end of the function". You probably want to write a comma (`,`) and call append...

Comment: The reason `append/3` no longer works is because **you defined your own one**.

Comment: oh my, i see.... THANKS :D